# Cleaner way to get a key and value from JSON

Tags: json, key-value

Currently the way that I am taking a JSON string where I "Don't know the contents" and pulling the keys and the values is as follows:

```
var arr     =   [{"manager_first_name":"jim","manager_last_name":"gaffigan"}];
var arrLen  =   arr.length;
for(var i = 0; i < arrLen; i++){
    var myKeys      =   Object.keys(arr[i]);
    var keysLen     =   myKeys.length;
    for(var x = 0; x < keysLen; x++){
        keyName     =   myKeys[x];
        keyValueStr =   "arr[i]."+keyName;
        keyValue    =   eval(keyValueStr);
        console.log(keyName+':'+keyValue);
    }
}
```

There has to be a cleaner and more efficient way of doing this. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: can you show one more member of your array `arr`?

Comment: unfortunately that is the complete JSON being returned. The information is being pulled form my database using PHP as an associative array. Then is turned into JSON with json_encode() which is then passed back to my front end via Jquey's $.get().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery you can use http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/ & Object.keys - Than:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('{"manager_first_name":"jim","manager_last_name":"gaffigan"}');
var keys = Object.keys(obj);
jQuery.each(keys,function(k, v){
    console.log(v);
    console.log(obj[v]);
});
```

Comment: I can't seem to make it work using your example. Here is what I am doing, http://jsfiddle.net/97Eu7/2/

Answer (score 0):

Create an object and initialize it with your JSON:

```
var arr     =   [{"manager_first_name":"jim","manager_last_name":"gaffigan"}];
var JSONObject = new MyJSONObject(arr);
```

in your constructor, set the object's properties.

Comment: the question is on javascript dude. see the console.log

Comment: Objects are illegal in javascript? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: everything is an object in javascript. but, pray, whats `MyJSONObject`? How does this answer solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [for-in loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) which iterates over the enumerable properties of an object, *in arbitrary order*.

```
var arr = [{"manager_first_name":"jim","manager_last_name":"gaffigan"}];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var currentObj = arr[i];
    for (var item in currentObj) {
        console.log(item + " : " + currentObj[item]);
    }
}
```

If your array always have only one item, you could omit the outermost for loop and just use `arr[0]`

```
var currentObj = arr[0];
for (var item in currentObj) {
    console.log(item + " : " + currentObj[item]);
}
```